# Oracle ADF: Unable to select a list item for second time

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello am developing a web application using oracle ADF(jDev12c). I have developed a page that contains a listView as below.

[image]

I have developed the above page using the blog [Implementing the Tree ...](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/implementing_the_tree_navigation_oracle)

The blog is really wonderful. Actually my problem is in above listview suppose that I have selected IT for the first time then I will get all the details related to IT. It is okay. When I come back from IT details I am unable to select IT for the second time. First I have to selected any item other that IT then I am able to select IT.

My Requirement is user is able to select any item for the second time also without selecting any other item.

Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After posting the question , I have done some google and luckily got some information to clear the selected item.

The following is the code to clear the selected item

```
myLiV.getSelectedRowKeys().clear();
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(myLiV);
```

I have binded my listView to a managed bean with name myLiV.

Got information from the following discussion

[Remove the highlighting of the selected row ...](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2326596)